# Serialization, for converting Object to Binary?

Tags: java

Someone told me that we use serialization only to convert object to binary? How far is that correct?

Comment: Why don't you read the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Comment: Have a look at my post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524162/use-of-serializable-other-than-writing-reading-object-to-from-file/31541629#31541629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the point is converting an object to binary. The only reason why anyone uses serialization is object storage - either in a file or in a database. The object can then be unserialized for later usage.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct

Class to be serialized needs to implement [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) or [Externalizable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html)

You may then use [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) to serialize and [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) to deserialize.  As these are IO streams they could be abstractions over a file, socket etc.